# Single theorem for hybrid of winding number and rotation number?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, curves

I am trying to make mathematical sense of some observations from my physics research, so I hope that you will bear with me.
For a complex-valued function $z(t)$ dependent on parameter $t$, I calculate the following integral along a closed loop $\gamma(t)=\gamma(x(t),y(t))$ living in 2D $(x,y)$ parameter space:

$$
W =\oint \text{darg } z(t) = \oint \text{Im} \frac{\dot{z}(t)}{z(t)},
$$

where the overhead dot is a derivative with respect to $t$. Notice that $\gamma(t)\in[x,y]$ is mapped to $z(t)\in\mathbb{C}$.

$W$ above may be interpreted as some winding number around the origin of the curve $z(t)$ in the complex plane. My issue is that, depending on the curve $\gamma(t)$, $W$ may behave as either a rotation number or a winding number. I interpret a **rotation number** as the total angle through which the tangent along the curve rotates (loop integral of curvature). For simple Jordan curves, this is always $\pm 1$.
On the other hand, I interpret the **winding number** as the number of times the complex loop $z(t)$ winds around a point (complex origin, in this case). If the loop does not enclose said point, the winding number is $0$.

However, my numerical observations suggest that $W$ above is a mix of both. For loops $\gamma(t)$ around $(x,y)$ points of special physical interest, $W$ gives a quantity that is useful in computing my final physical quantity (which is a topological index). It can take any integer value in general (not necessarily $\pm 1$). However, loops $\gamma(t)$ that do not enclose these special points also give nonzero $W$, and are always $\pm 1$.

An additional observation is that $z(x,y)$ is undefined (diverges to infinity) at these special points inside the loop $\gamma(x,y)$.

**Is there any single concept/theorem in math that might help me make sense of what I observe?** I found [Whitney's paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1937__4__276_0.pdf) that only discusses singularities *along* $z(t)$ (not *inside*). Additionally - correct me if I am wrong - but I do not think that one may use the definition of $W$ to define a complex vector field over $(x,y)$ since its definition is given in terms of the 1D parameter $t$.

(For those familiar with quantum mechanics, $z(t)$ is some complex-valued curve in projective Hilbert space mapped from an underlying 2D parameter space.)

Comment: Maybe not a whole answer, but at least it looks to me that what you are doing could just be an application of the residue-theorem from complex analysis. But to be honest, your notation of functions is rather non-mathematical so I am not sure, if I actually understand what you are doing.

Comment: It seems to me that your integral $W$ is exactly the winding number of $\gamma(t)$ around the origin. Indeed, this formula appears as the formula for $\text{Ind}_{\gamma}(z_0)$ here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Complex_analysis . Why is this not just winding number?

Comment: @mlk Thank you for the insight, and apologies for the lack of clarity. I thought about the residue-theorem before. However, this would still give me 0 in the absence of singularities, right (instead of $\pm 1$)? David The issue is that I get $\pm 1$ even in the absence of 2D parameter-space 'special points' (SP) in $z(x,y)$. It is hard to say that it is coincidence that $|W|$ can $>1$ only if the loop encloses such SP, while $W=\pm 1$ for all other loops not enclosing these SP. If it truly is a winding number / residue, I expect 0 instead of $\pm 1$. Maybe the correlation to SP is incorrect?

Comment: Well the point is that you are integrating $\dot{z}/z$, which will likely have a singularity at zero. In fact at least in the absence of other singularities I think this should result in just the winding number of the curve z\circ \gamma around zero.

Comment: @mlk Thank you. In trying to explain the $|W|>1$ cases, then, is it safe to say that these correspond to higher-order singularities/poles at the complex origin? Or is it other singularities not at the origin? Perhaps due to $\dot{z}$ being ill-defined, or $z=0$ (or undefined)? I am guessing that, in general, there is no way to relate these singularities to 'special points' in the underlying 2D parameter space, then? Sorry, I am just trying to understand how the singularity at the origin for $W=\pm 1$ cases differs from the case of $|W|>1$. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.